# Помогите пожалуйста с кодом

Tags: python

```
n = input()
b = []
for i in n:
    b += i
print(sum(b))
```

После проверки вылезает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 Файл "C:/Users/ilyak_000/Desktop/untitled-1.py", строка 5, из <module>

 print(sum(str(b)))

builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Вы сами-то можете прочитать этот вопрос? Потрудитесь отформатировать. Потом подумайте, что из себя представляет  `n`

Comment: Что именно должен делать ваш код? А то у вас столько нестыковок, что вообще не понятно, какие входные данные ожидаются и что вы хотите получить в результате.

Comment: В коде написано одно, в тексте ошибки другое... Не удивлюсь, если вопрос на самом деле вообще про что-нибудь третье.

Answer (score 1):

Я попытался угадать, что вы имели в виду, и вот так поправил ваш код. Но в будущем в таких случаях всегда пишите, какие данные у вас на входе, и что вы хотите получить в результате.

```
n = int(input())  # Здесь нужно привести строку из инпута к числу
b = []
for i in range(n):  # Здесь нужно вместо 'n' использовать range(n)
    b.append(i)  # Прибавить число к списку нельзя, нужно использовать append
print(sum(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно привести строку с числу. Вместо n = input() нужно использовать n = int(input())

Comment: судя по дальнейшему использованию, ожидается ввод списка и понадобится split